# Minimum value of $ f(x) = x\log_2x +(1-x)\log_2(1-x) $

Tags: functions, logarithms

What is the minimum value of the following function for $ 0<x<1 $ ? Here the base of logarithm is 2 .

$ f(x) = x\log_2x +(1-x)\log_2(1-x) $

Comment: Hint: By a change of base formula you can change the base to $e$. Then you can use tools from calculus for the answer.

Comment: You don't even need to change the base to apply the tools from calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the base you have $\log_2x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$. So you have
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}\left(x\ln x+(1−x)\ln(1−x)\right)
$$
and 
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}\left(\ln x-\ln(1−x)\right)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}\ln\left(\frac{x}{1−x}\right)
$$
So $f'=0$ for $\frac{x}{1−x}=1$, i.e. $x=1/2$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one must check the endpoints of the domain as well, i.e. show that as $f(x) \geq f(\frac{1}{2})$ for $x \to 0, 1$. (Or you could argue that $f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$)